# How to use Google Cloud KMS key as SigningCredential in IdentityServer4?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, identityserver4

I have an IdentityServer4 app running on App Engine. As I prepare for production, I have a lot of confusion using `.AddSigningCredential()` in this scenario. In app engine, I don't have a file system to cert store in a traditional sense, and it seems like I can only pass in a path to a cert/key or the contents itself.

As I'm hosting on Google Cloud, I would like to use KMS. The API for KMS gives me the ability to sign something, but Identity Server doesn't give me a way to use that, and I don't see a way for KMS to give Identity server what *it* wants.

The only workaround I came up with is to generate a key pair, save it as a secret, and pass that in to `.AddSigningCredential()`. The downside is that now I have to manage this key/secret manually. There must be another way.

Comment: Can you provide more information about your setup? You can use [bucket storage with App Engine](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java/using-cloud-storage#using_cloud_storage_with_app_engine) if you just want to host static content.

Comment: I'm hosting IdentityServer4 on App Engine flex, .net core 3.1. I do not intend to host purely static content. How else can I clarify?